# How to speed up the function DelaunayTriangulation?

Tags: performance-tuning, computational-geometry

First define a function `meshGrid` to generate some points:

```
meshGrid[{x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_}, h0_] := 
  With[{yh0 = h0*Sqrt[3.]/2}, 
    Array[{(#1 - 1)*h0 + x1 + (1 + (-1)^#2) h0/4, (#2 - 1)*yh0 + 
        y1} &, Ceiling@{(x2 - x1)/h0, (y2 - y1)/yh0}]]~Flatten~1;

p = meshGrid[{-1, 1, -1, 1}, 0.05];
```

The computing time of `DelaunayTriangulation`:

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"];
DelaunayTriangulation[p] // Timing // First
```

In my computer it gives `18.533s`

Matlab saves much time if does the same thing:

[image]

**====================================Update=====================================**

@halirutan really made a great attempt to point the way, but I failed to compile and didn't get the right answer, maybe I should learn something before. Here I find another way in this [blogpost](http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2008/10/qhull-for-mathematica.html), which also relates to Qhull but easier to implement. You can get more infomation from [here](http://xcellerator.info/mPower/index.html). Before changing anything, two files need to be downloaded, one is [mPower](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlr8r/files/mQhull%20and%20mPower/), from which we need is mPower.m, another one is [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/download/).

You can get the rest steps from that blog, only step two is worthy of note:

step 2: download qhull for windows, you may need to change the name, and put it into the folder C:\qhull. **Then Copy all the *.exe files in bin folder and paste them in folder qhull, errors will occur without this step.**

Comment: Now if only there were a way to leverage `Graphics\`Mesh\`Delaunay[]`...

Comment: In this specific case it could  probably be done a lot faster given the regular nature of your points.  Is that of any value to you?

Comment: @J.M. don't leave us guessing!

Comment: @J.M. I can't find any infomation about in help, how to use it

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am not sure what the regular nature mean

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I honestly don't know! I keep seeing all these neat-looking functions after spelunking, and I keep wondering about how to exploit them...

Comment: paradox2, I mean it is a nice even grid of points already in order, so it should be possible to get the triangulation with a simple algorithm.  Is this kind of data representative of your application or is it just a dummy set?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will use DelaunayTriangulation in many different situations,can't guarantee regular pattern, so I want to speed it up

Comment: Is the ComputationalGeometry package in version 8 still ":Package Version: 2.0" for mma4?  If it is I imagine there is a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, yep, still version 2.0 in version 8; clearly that package has not been touched in a while...

Comment: @paradox2 It might not be of concern for you, but you should note that the results returned by Mathematica and Matlab are not the same, even though they represent the same triangulation. Mathematica represents triangulation by a list of vertex adjecency lists for each input vertex, while MATLAB returns the indices making up each triangle.

Comment: paradox2 please consider posting the the method described in the Blog post as an answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, it is possible to speed up the Delaunay-triangulation and make it as fast as it is in Matlab.

If you are not afraid of some setup-work, then one possibility is to use a package which calls a c-implementation of the Delaunay-triangulation. One package I know is [qh-math](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1160/) which is available in the Wolfram-library:

> This package includes source code and support files needed to create a MathLink-based interface to the Qhull library (http://www.qhull.org) algorithm for Delaunay Triangulation. The sources are based on work done originally by Alban Tsui at the Imperial College of Science, Technology and Medicine.

And btw, this is exactly what Matlab is using: http://www.qhull.org/html/qh-faq.htm#math

### Usage

I assume the program `qh-math.exe` is located in my download-folder. For your system you have to change this in the `Install` call. The usage is pretty easy. First you `Install` the MathLink program and after this you can call `qDelaunayTriangulation[..]` like a normal Mathemtatica function:

```
lnk = Install["/home/patrick/Downloads/qh-math/qh-math.exe"];
```

And then you can triangulate your points

```
meshGrid[{x1_, x2_, y1_, y2_}, h0_] := 
  With[{yh0 = h0*Sqrt[3.]/2}, 
    Array[{(#1 - 1)*h0 + x1 + (1 + (-1)^#2) h0/4, (#2 - 1)*yh0 + 
        y1} &, Ceiling@{(x2 - x1)/h0, (y2 - y1)/yh0}]]~Flatten~1;
p = meshGrid[{-1, 1, -1, 1}, 0.05];

{t, del} = AbsoluteTiming[qDelaunayTriangulation[p]];
```

On my machine this took only `t=0.032471` seconds. The the result looks nice

```
Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[29, First[#2]], 
    Polygon[#1]} &, (Part[p, #] & /@ del)]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that the output is different from `DelaunayTriangulation`. This version really gives a triangle index list like `{{5, 6, 2}, {10, 7, 4}, {1, 5, 6},...`.

### Freshly compiled qh-math.exe for Windows

Due to the great efforts of @Oleksandr R. we have now compiled versions of `qh-math.exe` and all the commandline tools from *qhull*. Please download a zip with all files for your system:

- [qhull.zip for 64bit Windows](https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/qhull64.zip)
- [qhull.zip for 32bit Windows](https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/qhull32.zip)

### Compiling your own qh-math

I'm on Linux here and since there is no executable program included I had to compile it by myself. Since it can happen, that your program does not work (it's kind of old) you may have to compile it for your machine too. Therefore, I explain it step by step

**Compiling:** First you download the [archive with the sources](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1160/qh-math.tar.gz?file_id=1747) and unpack it. The following steps all takes place in the terminal. On Windoze you may want to do this in Visual Studio or with Cygwin.

First I store the path-name to my dev-directory of MathLink in a variable

```sh
MROOT="/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/\
 DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/"
```

Then I had to install the `qhull` development files. Here, I could use my package manager, while on other systems you may need to download and install it from the [home page of qhull](http://www.qhull.org/).

```sh
sudo apt-get install libqhull-dev
```

Then you go into the unpacked folder of *qh-math* and use `mprep` of Mathematica to process the template file

```sh
$MROOT/mprep -o qh-math.tm.c qh-math.tm
```

Now you can compile the sources into a MathLink program

```sh
gcc -I${MROOT} -L${MROOT} -I/usr/include/qhull -lqhull -lML64i3 -lm \
 -lpthread -lrt -lstdc++ qh-math.c qh-math.tm.c
```

If you use a recent version of qhull you have to rename the variable in `qh-math.c`

```c
char qh_version[] = "qh-math.c 2000/7/6";
```

into maybe `qh_version_blub`. Otherwise it clashes with a definition in the qhull lib.

The final MathLink program `qh-math.exe` is now ready to use in this directory.

Comment: There is an exe file for windows,how can I implement it in my program? I have never used MathLink before, is there any tutorials for me to follow

Comment: very pretty triangles.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I have version 2009.1-1 here. Except for the adjustment of the one variable name I did not change anything. Although, there were warnings about types during compilation which maybe fatal on other machines. [Chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Comment: @paradox2 Does it work for you? Could you use the binary program or did you recompiled it for yourself? Oleksandr had serious trouble compiling a working solution.

Comment: @halirutan Sorry, I know nothing about compiling, I even can't get the compiled file

Comment: @paradox2 turns out I was doing something silly when trying to compile it the last time around. You can get the qhull and qh-math Windows binaries [here](http://ge.tt/8JcSZ5Q). The 32-bit version can be used with both 32- and 64-bit versions of Windows and/or *Mathematica*, but the 64-bit one is a bit faster if you can use it.

Comment: @paradox2 I saw the update in your question. Nonetheless, you should try to use Oleksandrs ready to use files. I added a download section in the middle of my answer.

Comment: @OleksandrR.,halirutan Wow,it runs perfectly on my laptop,and without a window flickering(happened in my updated method), what else can I say? Both of you deserve credit for unremitting exploration.

Comment: Why isn't this the default and integrated with MMA?

Comment: A correction: MATLAB uses Qhull for `delaunayn` and related functions: N-dimensional Delaunay triangulations.  For 2D (and maybe for 3D) it uses [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org), which is MUCH faster than Qhull: benchmark `delaunay` vs `delanayn` in MATLAB.  There are libraries which are again considerably faster than CGAL, e.g. [Triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html).

Comment: Correction to my correction: `delaunay()` may not be based on CGAL, but there's a CGAL-based triangulator as well in MATLAB: the DelunayTri class ([reference](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/07/15/computational-geometry-in-matlab-r2009a-part-i/#7))

Comment: I timed `delaunay()` vs `DelunayTri`, and both give the same timings, so I assume they both use CGAL as the back end.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]
mo = Delaunay[mypts];
faces = mo@"FaceCoordinates"
```

then `Polygon[faces]` is the triangulation.

Comment: Have you read the answer of @Simon? He uses kind of the same approach. Can you explain in detail, how your solution is different?

Comment: @hal, OTOH, Ulises provides a slightly more convenient way to extract the coordinates of the triangulation. After executing `dt = Delaunay[meshGrid[{-1, 1, -1, 1}, 0.05]];`, one can now do either `Graphics[GraphicsComplex[dt["Coordinates"], {EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], Polygon[dt["Faces"]]}]]` to get a picture like the one in Simon's answer, or `Graphics[MapIndexed[{ColorData[29, First[#2]], Polygon[#1]} &, dt["FaceCoordinates"]]]` to get a picture like the one in your answer.

Comment: Ulises, if you could be kind enough to share and elaborate on the properties of a `MeshObject[]` that can be exposed, your answer would be certainly more useful...

Comment: @J.M., I've discovered a few: `dt /@ {"MeshElements", "Faces", "Edges", "Coordinates", "VertexCoordinates", "EdgeCoordinates", "FaceCoordinates", "Dimension"}`.

Comment: @Simon, neat! How'd you manage to spelunk these? (I only found `"Faces"` and `"Coordinates"` through trial and error.)

Comment: @J.M., a bit of lucky guesswork and a bit of poring over the `DownValues` of ``Graphics`Mesh`*`` symbols. No clever spelunking tricks I'm afraid :-)

Comment: I knew you will be able to figure out the names of some of the most useful properties :-). I am traveling now, so I can only give short answer on  a tiny screen...

Answer (score 10):

As J.M. suggested in a comment, the `Delaunay` function in `` Graphics`Mesh `` can be used for this, though my method for getting the data out is somewhat unsatisfying.

The `Delaunay` function will take a list of points in 2D and return a `MeshObject`. Looking at the `InputForm` of the `MeshObject` one can see a list of the original points and a list of integer triplets corresponding to the points making up each triangle. Perhaps one of the functions in the package will extract this data from the `MeshObject` but I couldn't find it. Nor could I extract the relevant parts using normal expression manipulations. I resorted to converting the `InputForm` to a string in order to replace `MeshObject` with `List`.

The code is not as fast as the other solutions, but it is much quicker than the `ComputationalGeometry` triangulation. It runs in about 0.3 seconds on my PC.

```
p = meshGrid[{-1, 1, -1, 1}, 0.05];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

extractTriangulation[mo_] := 
 ToExpression[StringReplace[ToString[InputForm[mo]], "MeshObject" -> "List"]][[3, 2]]

del = extractTriangulation@Delaunay@p;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], GraphicsComplex @@ MapAt[Polygon, del, 2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't get your method to work with version 7.  FWIW typically you can use patterns to extract data from pseudo-atomic objects, e.g. `SparseArray[Range@9] /. _[data__] :> {data}`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ``Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]`` loads the package, so `Delaunay` can be used without a context. what happens in v7, does `Delaunay[p]` give you anything at all?

Comment: I didn't realize that.  I get a MeshObject but InputForm only returns `MeshObject[None, None]`.  Interestingly I see something if I use `GeometryPlot[Delaunay@p]` so there *is* something there, but neither `InputForm` nor `/. _[data___]` appear to access it in v7.

Answer (score 4):

Fast Delaunay triangulations are sorely missing from Mathematica. I really hope the next version will have them.

To complement the other excellent answers, here's how to access MATLAB's [CGAL based](http://www.cgal.org/) Delaunay triangulator (`delaunay`) from Mathematica:

First, install the [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) package. Now load it and set up the `delaunay` function:

```
Needs["MATLink`"]
OpenMATLAB[]

delaunay = Composition[Round, MFunction["delaunay"]];
```

Now you can simply evaluate `delaunay[points]` to get the triangles, represented as point indices.

Note: in MATLAB, `delaunay`, which is based on CGAL, is faster than `delaunayn` which is based on Qhull.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of MATLink.  The reason why I posted this answer is that I have referenced this question more than once and I wanted to give one more *practically usable* and *fast* method.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately I only have matlab2009 to try, but it seems I can only use the function once before the link crashes, and only with less than 1500 points. Is that a known current limitation ? (Mac OSX Mountain Lion, Mathematica 8)

Comment: @lalmei I'm not sure what you mean by "the link crashes", but why don't you send me an email (matlink.m@gmail.com) with a complete description of the problem and *complete* version info (Mma, MATLAB, MatLink, your OS, 32/64 bit, student version or not)?  We don't really support that MATLAB version but it may be possible to fix the problem.

Comment: @lalmei Please just send an email to the address above, with all details included, so we can debug and fix this issue.

Comment: @lalmei I haven't heard from you since your comment.  Did the problem go away for you?

Answer (score 4):

Version 10 (which is at the moment publicly accessible through the Programming Cloud) includes the [`DelaunayMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DelaunayMesh.html) and [`VoronoiMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html) functions.

They work for 1D, 2D or 3D point sets.  Example:

```
points = RandomReal[1, {100,2}];

mesh = DelaunayMesh[points]
```

Now various properties of the triangulation can be queried using `mesh["some-property"]`.  Available properties can be listed using `mesh["Properties"]`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) really useful in finding the answer to the same question, so I thought I'd just leave the exact way to do it here in case someone stumbles across it like I did. The speed boost is very good - I'd been relying on this function to get the output I needed and for a list of about 3000 points it was taking about 20 seconds on my machine using DelaunayTriangulation and about 0.1 for the below equivalent!

```
points=RandomReal[1,{100,2}];
vertexadjacency = DelaunayMesh[points]["VertexVertexConnectivity"]
```