# ListDensityPlot performance when scaling axes

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I need to visualize 3D data having 200*200 data points. 
`ListDensityPlot` is a good candidate, but it seems to have strange performance issues.
I created a small test that plots 40000 points. It has three cases: using 2D array as input, using array of 3D points with integer coordinates $(x,y)$ and using array of 3D points with float coordinates $(x,y)$.

```
    TestFunction[x_, y_] := Sin[Pi/20* Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]];
    testdata = Table[TestFunction[i, j], {i, -100, 100}, {j, -100, 100}];
    testdataPoints = 
      Flatten[Table[{i, j, TestFunction[i, j]}, {i, -100, 100}, {j, -100, 
         100}], 1];
    testdataPoints2 = 
      Flatten[Table[{i*0.01, j*0.01, TestFunction[i, j]}, {i, -100, 
         100}, {j, -100, 100}], 1];
Benchmark[d_, n_] := 
  Timing[ListDensityPlot[d, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PlotRange -> Full, InterpolationOrder -> n]];
TableForm[
 Table[Benchmark[data, 
   n], {data, {testdata, testdataPoints, testdataPoints2}}, {n, 0, 
   2}], TableHeadings -> {{"Array", "Integer", "Float"}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: density plots of different data]

It gives pretty strange result. When I simply scale axes and my coordinates are not integer anymore (the case is called "Float"). The performance drops almost 10 times (3 seconds vs 25 seconds).

Here's the output timing:

```
            0         1         2
Array   0.834276 2.96802    3.05685  
Integer 4.84968  3.42562    3.19835
Float   27.5574   26.1669   25.9262
```

Any explanation for such behavior?

## **Edit**

As alternative to Michael's solution one can use `ArrayPlot` (as Silvia suggested) if interpolation is not important.
It can be easily scaled to look like "Float" case.

Comment: "I can't post image" - can you post it somewhere else, like [imgur](http://imgur.com/), and then link to the image in your post?

Comment: I don't think image really matters, but you can easily run the test code. The generated images are identical (as my eye sees that). It's timing that puzzles me

Comment: Anyway... what is the result of applying ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[]`` on your three lists?

Comment: ``Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {testdata, testdataPoints, testdataPoints2}``  gives `{False, False, False}`.

Comment: By the way, using `Interpolation`, `DensityPlot` and `PlotPoints -> 101` is faster for me than `ListDensityPlot`. (Not an answer to your Q, though.)

Comment: Well, can you do another set of tests, with packed versions of your lists? (e.g. ``packedtestdata = Developer`ToPackedArray[testdata]``).

Comment: @0x4A4D He needs to `N` to the data first: ``Developer`ToPackedArray[N[testdata]]``.

Comment: This is probably because the Delaunay triangulation used by `ListDensityPlot` is very inefficient. See [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13437/5) for some details.

Comment: @0x4A4D It gives same results

Comment: @Michael E2 `packedtestdata = 
  Developer``ToPackedArray /@ {N[testdata], N[testdataPoints], 
    N[testdataPoints2]};` Gives same result, maybe a fraction of second less

Comment: I dont' know how to escape the "`"

Comment: @rm-rf how is triangulation more effective for integer (x,y)?

Comment: @BlacKow You need to use double back-ticks to wrap a inline code which contains back-tick.

Comment: @BlacKow Sorry, but I'm not a triangulation expert, so I don't know the answer to that (or if that indeed is the reason). All I know is that the built-in Delaunay triangulation is inefficient for all but small 2D lists... 0x4A4D or Szabolcs or halirutan might be able to shed more light on it, if they happen to see this question.

Comment: You can always use the poor man's `ListDensityPlot`, that is the `ArrayPlot`.

Comment: @Silvia Yes, I can, but then I need to deal with labeling the axes with `FrameTicks` which is an additional effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

Packing the data, as @0x4A4D suggests, seems to "fix" the problem, except in `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.  See [What is a Mathematica packed array?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) for an explanation of the importance of packed arrays.

```
TableForm[
 ParallelTable[
  Benchmark[data, n],
  {data,  Developer`ToPackedArray /@ N@{testdata, testdataPoints, testdataPoints2}},
  {n, 0, 2}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Array", "Integer", "Float"}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: Table of output]

This way is faster:

```
TableForm[
 Table[
  Timing[
   ifn = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> n]; 
   DensityPlot[ifn[i, j],
    {i, -1, 1}, {j, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 101, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> Full]],
  {data, {testdataPoints2}}, {n, 0, 2}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{"Float"}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

[image: Second table output]

Comment: Your last code need about 39, 40, 37 seconds for each `InterpolationOrder` settings respectively, while OP's code needs 46, 36, 35 seconds. Well I guess I really should upgrade my computer...

Comment: @Silvia I'm on an 2.7GHz i7 Mac, 16GB RAM.

Comment: In my case - OS X, Mathematica 8 -  the packing gives: 16.9, 13.9, 13.7 for "Float" case, so its twice faster but it is still significantly slower than "Integer" case, which is really bizarre.

Comment: The last code gives 0.84, 0.82, 0.88, so its's a nice workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using a core 2 quad CPU @2.4GHz and 8G RAM. So it seems not quite natural to take such a long time on my PC?