# How to draw grid lines on top of a plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to use `ArrayPlot` instead of a `DensityPlot` because it seems to be faster ([more here)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/listdensityplot-performance-when-scaling-axes)
I still want axes ticks to have real values and not array index.

I came up with following code which basically centers and scales `ArrayPlot` according to `PlotRange` given to `Graphics`:

```
arrayPlot[data_, opts___] := 
  Module[{dim = Dimensions[data] // N, rls, range, imgSz, aRatio, 
    cf},
   rls = {opts}~
     Join~{PlotRange -> Transpose@{{1, 1}, dim}, 
      ImageSize -> {500, 300}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"};
   {range, cf} = {PlotRange, ColorFunction} /. rls;
   aRatio = 1/Divide @@ (ImageSize /. rls);
   Graphics[{Scale[#, (range.{-1, 1})*dim^-1] &@
          Translate[#, (range.{1, 1} - dim)*0.5] &@
        First@ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> cf, 
          DataReversed -> True]}, Frame -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> aRatio, #] & @@ rls
   ];
```

It works OK and with:

```
dataP[m_, n_] := Table[i*Boole[j < i], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];
arrayPlot[dataP[100, 100], ImageSize -> {500, 500}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {{-21, 23}, {-1, 1}}]
```

I get

[image]

If I modify a arrayPlot with `GridLines -> Automatic , GridLinesStyle -> 
 Directive[Orange, Thickness[0.05]]` added to `Graphics`, I get gridlines behind the plot.
[image]

How can I make the grid lines appear in front of the plot? It is possible to add `Mesh` to `ArrayPlot`, but I want to avoid it since it will require synchronization of mesh with axes ticks.

## Edit

Considering answer by 'rm -rf' the updated function is:

```
arrayPlot[data_, opts___] := 
  Module[{dim = Dimensions[data] // N, rls, range, imgSz, aRatio, 
    cf},
   rls = {opts}~
     Join~{PlotRange -> Transpose@{{1, 1}, dim}, 
      ImageSize -> {500, 300}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
      Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}};
   {range, cf} = {PlotRange, ColorFunction} /. rls;
   aRatio = 1/Divide @@ (ImageSize /. rls);
   rls = Select[rls, 
   MatchQ[#, Alternatives @@ (#[[1]] & /@ Options[Graphics]) -> _] &];
   Graphics[{Scale[#, (range.{-1, 1})*dim^-1] &@
          Translate[#, (range.{1, 1} - dim)*0.5] &@
        First@ArrayPlot[data, ColorFunction -> cf, 
          DataReversed -> True]}, Frame -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> aRatio, ##] & @@ rls
   ];

arrayPlot[dataP[100, 100], GridLines -> Automatic , 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Orange, Thickness[0.01]], 
 ImageSize -> {500, 500}, PlotRange -> {{-28, 23}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Comment: This has been used [a few times](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=GridLinesInFront) on this site, but AFAIK, this is the first question that directly addresses it.

Comment: Have you tried the `DataRange` option?  This produces your basic plot: `Show[
 ArrayPlot[dataP[100, 100], ImageSize -> {500, 500}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", DataReversed -> True,
  DataRange -> {{-21, 23}, {-1, 1}}],
 FrameTicks -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1]`  Grid lines can be added á la [rm -rf](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5)'s answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well... This is exactly what I wanted. I knew there should be a way simpler than my manual stitching and passing options through :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Word of warning: data range in case of `ArrayPlot` [has bugs](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30404/arrayplot-and-non-integer-plotrange).

Comment: @Johu Thanks.  I added another workaround to the answers your question received.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

*Edit*:

As of V11 `"GridLinesInFront"` was documented together with `"AxesInFront"`, `"FrameInFront"` and `"TransparentPolygonMesh"`

---

You need to use the <strike>undocumented</strike> option

```
Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
```

to make the grid lines appear on top of your plot. This should give you:

[image]

Comment: Since Google brought me here, this is a good place to mention another undocumented option, `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}`, which does what it says on the tin.

Comment: Both those method options and a couple more are now documented, under **Graphics > Options > Method.**