# ArrayPlot and non-integer PlotRange

Tags: plotting

There seems to weird bug regarding non-integer `PlotRange` in `ArrayPlot`. For example...

```
ArrayPlot[
   Table[Sin[x/50 π] Tanh[y/50 π], {y, 100}, {x, 100}],
   DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.5, .9}}
]
```

gives an error:

> Value of option PlotRange -> {{0,1},{0.5,0.9}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications.

The same code works, if one of the plot range parameters for y-axes is turned into an integer.

Did I do smth wrong? Is there a workaround?

I need to use array plot as `ListContourPlot` is too slow for large datasets and `MatrixPlot` has the same problem.

I am using *Mathematica* 8 64 bit version on linux.

**Edit**

After some more testing I see, that it works whenever PlotRange includes at least one integer. For example `PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.5, 1.2}}` works as it includes 1. So one possible workaround is just to scale the range, such that max-min would be larger than 1.

But I am still looking forward, if anyone finds a way to have shorter than 1 range on the axes. Dirty way would be just using manual 'Ticks'.

**Edit 2**

Possible workaround.

As I wrote in the previous edit, it works, then the range includes at least one integer. So one could just scale the range. Here is a naive hard-coded example how it might be done.

```
ArrayPlot[
   Table[Sin[x/50 π] Tanh[y/50 π], {y, 100}, {x, 100}],
   DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1} 10}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.1, 0.8} 10}, 
   FrameTicks -> {Table[{y, ToString[y/10 // N]}, {y, 1, 8, 1}], 
   Table[{x, ToString[x // N]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.25}]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

This means that I have bypassed the only side-effect of scaling the range, which is messing up the tick labels.

I would submit it as a solution, when I have waited my 8 hours and there is no nicer one proposed.

Comment: This is actually quite a good question as one would assume that when using a `DataRange` the `PlotRange` you used should be valid, but it's not.  I notice that this question is tagged `version-8` -- I have the same problem in version 7 so this is not specific to v8 only.

Comment: I also tested in version 9. The problem does not seem to be version specific. I removed the tag. Thanks @Mr.Wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround that works in V7,8,9,10 (the underlying problem persists):

```
Show[
 ArrayPlot[
  Table[Sin[x/50 π] Tanh[y/50 π], {y, 100}, {x, 100}], 
  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.5, .9}}, FrameTicks -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Now I think this is the best workaround.

Answer (score 4):

All observations that follow were made using *Mathematica* 7.

---

The problem is that deep in the option processing of `ArrayPlot`, `Floor` and `Ceiling` are used on the numeric values in the PlotRange option value.  This is evidenced by Blocking these function while calling `ArrayPlot`:

```
Block[{Floor = Identity, Ceiling = Identity},
 ArrayPlot[
  Table[Sin[x/50 π] Tanh[y/50 π], {y, 100}, {x, 100}],
  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.5, .9}},
  FrameTicks -> All
 ]
]
```

[image]

This actually works just fine here and we get the desired plot, but this fix is hardly "safe" as it's impossible to guess what other steps in the plot creation are altered by this.

I am continuing to dig through internal code but even if I find a fix for version 7 there is no guarantee that it will be easily ported to later versions.

---

In version 7 the two functions that need to be modified are:

- `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`ArrayTicks ``
- `` Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`getRange ``

Comment: This is probably the same bug that affects `DataRange` in `ArrayPlot`... you get a `First::first` error if both extents of the limit have the same `Floor` value. Example: `ArrayPlot[RandomReal[1, {10, 10}], DataRange -> {{0.2, 0.4}, {0, 1}}, 
 FrameTicks -> True]`

Comment: @rm-rf That one is caused by ``Private`ArrayTicks``, yes.  `getRange` is more significant in the case above because that's what ends up halting evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

From help

```
PlotRange -> {{ imin,imax }, {jmin ,jmax }} shows only elements 
with and in the specified ranges. The top-left element has , 
increases down the page; increases to the right.
```

[image]
So these are index values.  You can't use `.5` and `.9` or even zero.

```
ArrayPlot[
 N@Table[Sin[x/50 π] Tanh[y/50 π], {y, 100}, {x, 100}], 
 PlotRange -> {{30, 50}, {30, 100}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You said : `The same code works, if one of the plot range parameters for y-axes is turned into an integer`

Can you should the code you used for this? I am not following.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPlot.html

Comment: `ArrayPlot[Table[Sin[x/50 \[Pi]] Tanh[y/50 \[Pi]], {y, 100}, {x, 100}],
  DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.5}}]` This seems to work funny enough.

Comment: This all makes no sense. I think this is a bug. According to help, `PlotRange` is element index. It says right there `with top left element has i=1,j=1`.

Comment: The text in help is valid only while you have not specified `DataRange`. It is not an index in this case.

Example:
ArrayPlot[Table[Sin[x/50 \[Pi]] Tanh[y/50 \[Pi]], {y, 100}, {x, 100}],
  DataRange -> {{10, 20}, {10, 20}}, PlotRange -> {{10, 20}, {0, 30}}]

Comment: You say `The text in help is valid only while you have not specified DataRange` Where did you read that? `PlotRange` has 4 different forms. If you use the form you showed, then it means an index. Period. The help is clear. I say this is a bug. But what do I know.

Comment: I did not read that. I see how it acts when I use combination of other options. I also told it was a bug and asked for a workaround.

Comment: @Johu The workaround is to assume these are indices and use them as such. You showed a case where they `worked` when these are not indices (since an index can't be zero nor fraction), then I say this should not have worked and this looks like a bug to me. But please wait for others to look at this. This is what I know myself now from looking at help.

Comment: @Nasser I agree with you now. Probably it was not meant to be used as did I. I did not get you before.