# Combining graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

## Original question

I would like to put a coloured grid behind the following plot:

[image]

which was generated by:

```
a = Table[x, {x, 1, 10}];
b = Table[10 x, {x, 1, 10}];
ListLinePlot[{Table[x^2, {x, 1, 10}]}, InterpolationOrder -> 0,
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}}, GridLines -> {a, b}, GridLinesStyle ->   
Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

so that I could shade certain squares of the grid so it looks something like:

[image]

for example.

## Update1

Using Kuba's code below, it is fairly straightforward to overlay an x^2 shaded plot with an x^3 ListLinePlot using the following code:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}];
ceiling = {#, Ceiling[#2 + 1, 10]} & @@@ data;
floor = {#, Floor[#2, 10]} & @@@ data;
a = Table[x, {x, 1, 10}];
b = Table[10 x, {x, 1, 10}];
c = ListLinePlot[{Table[x^3, {x, 1, 10}]}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}}, GridLines -> {a, b}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Thick}];
Show[ListPlot[{data, ceiling, floor}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, Filling -> (2 -> {3}), 
GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[0, 100, 10]}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
PlotStyle -> {None, None, None}], c]
```

which generates:

[image]

without too much fiddling. Is there a similarly straightforward way of showing a shaded x^3 plot & ListLinePlot x^2 without running into problems with the dimensions of the grid (without fiddling around with the dimensions each time)?

## Update2

Thanks to Kuba's code:

[image]

with:

```
lineData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, min, max}];
shadeData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := 
Transpose[{{#, Ceiling[#2 + 1, 10]}, {#, Floor[#2, 10]}} & @@@ 
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, min, max}]]

With[{stdOpt = {InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[0, 300, 10]}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1}}, 
ListPlot[{lineData[#^2 &, 10], ##} & @@ shadeData[#^3 &, 10], 
Filling -> (2 -> {3}), PlotStyle -> {Thick, None, None}, stdOpt, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 100}},

Epilog -> {Red, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[{1, 10}, {2, 20}], Blue, 
Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[{2, 40}, {3, 50}]}

]]
```

## Update3

Having some fun with it:
[image]

with:

```
shadeData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := 
Transpose@Table[{{x, Ceiling[f[x] + If[FractionalPart[f[x]] == 0.5, 0.5, 0], 1]},
{x, Floor[f[x], 1]}}, {x, min, max}]

Animate[Quiet[With[{stdOpt = {InterpolationOrder -> 0, GridLines -> {Range[-10, 28,
1], Range[-10, 14]}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], 
Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.25}}, ListPlot[shadeData[(Sin[# + n])*10 &, 28], 
Filling -> (2 -> {1}), FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Orange], 
PlotStyle -> {None, None, None}, stdOpt, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
ImageSize -> 600, PlotRange -> {{0, 24}, {-10, 10}}]]], {n, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
AnimationDirection -> Forward, AnimationRate -> 0.5]
```

and

[image]

...etc :)

Comment: You will need to use `Graphics` and `Rectanlge` to build this directly, instead of using an existing plotting function.  Have you tried this route already?  Take a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html).

Comment: I have tried positioning rectangles behind the plot using `Inset`, but it proved to be difficult to position them :/

Comment: You don't need `Inset` because `Rectangle` is a graphics primitive.  `Inset` is for putting things that are *not* graphics primitives into `Graphics`. Just use a `Table` to generate the list of `Rectangle`s with appropriate coordinates.

Comment: OK thanks - I'll give that a go :)

Comment: You may need to use [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28025/12) for better looks after all the other pieces came together.

Comment: Tried `Show`, & `ArrayPlot[Table[GCD[i, j], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]]` ... no good! - Will go back to your original suggestion - thanks for the other link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no need to use grapics primitives:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2}, {x, 0, 10}];
ceiling = {#, Ceiling[#2 + 1, 10]} & @@@ data;
floor = {#, Floor[#2, 10]} & @@@ data;

ListPlot[{data, ceiling, floor}, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> 1,
   Filling -> (2 -> {3}), GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[0, 100, 10]}, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], PlotStyle -> {Thick, None, None}]
```

[image]

---

Response to the edit with a general approach. We don't need `Show`. I've also added single `Rectangle` with `Epilog` as you asked.

```
lineData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, min, max}];
shadeData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := Transpose @
  Table[{{x, Ceiling[f[x] + If[FractionalPart[f[x]] == 0, 1, 0], 10]}, 
         {x, Floor[f[x], 10]}}
       , {x, min, max}]

With[{stdOpt = {InterpolationOrder -> 0, GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[0, 300, 10]}, 
      GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.8], Dashed], Joined -> True,
      AspectRatio -> 1}},

 ListPlot[{lineData[#^2 &, 6], ##} & @@ shadeData[#^3 &, 6], 
          Filling -> (2 -> {3}), PlotStyle -> {Thick, None, None}, stdOpt, 
          Epilog -> Rectangle[{1, 50}, {2, 60}]] ]
```

[image]

Comment: @Blackbird Thanks :)

Comment: @Kuba - Thanks! Great. Now if I wanted to colour, say, x^3, and ListLinePlot x^2, I suppose I would use `Show`? Just having a little trouble with scaling when I do that :/

Comment: @Kuba, please see update - want to keep it fairly flexible if poss.

Comment: @Kuba, also(!) (though not as important) is it possible to use the same floor/ceiling concept with a ListPlot using coordinates - thereby letting me choose which squares to shade, independent of ListLinePlot?

Comment: @martin for manually choosen rectangles there is no purpose for usage of `Floor`. Is the edit ok? ;)

Comment: @Kuba, thank you very much for the time you spent on this - it is exactly what I was after :) I will have a play!

Comment: @martin `Epilog-> {...}` and in `...` you can put whatever you want that would work in `Graphics`.

Comment: @martin you probably wanted to edit the question not th answer :)

Comment: @martin use this: `shadeData[f_, max_, min_: 0] := 
 Transpose@
  Table[{{x, 
     Ceiling[f[x] + If[FractionalPart[f[x]] == 0, 1, 0], 10]}, {x, 
     Floor[f[x], 10]}}, {x, min, max}]`. Also, please delete your previous comments that are no longer important ;)