# How to have a special grid as background of a plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to have a grid background for the function `(2/5)*x+3/5` but with one small detail. I want the coordinates of the points to be in the centres of the background squares, not on their corners. I am playing with [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#The_algorithm) so I want to see nearest to the centre of which squares a line goes through.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want but this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37460/5478 is related for sure.

Comment: I want to shift the GridLines by 0.5 to the right and down, so that the point (1;1) for example is exactly in the middle of a square of a grid instead of on a corner.

Comment: Something like `Plot[(2/5)*x + 3/5, {x, 0, 20}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[.5, 20, 1], Range[.5, 20, 1]}, AspectRatio -> .5,
  ImageSize -> 500, 
 Prolog -> 
  RegionPlot[
    Floor[(2/5)*x + 3/5] - .0 <= y <= Ceiling[(2/5)*x + 3/5] + .0, {x,
      0, 20}, {y, 0, 10}, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> .5, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]][[1]]]`

(This is just to get some idea of what you're after, not any real solution).

Comment: Yes, @rasher, this is exactly what I want, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @AlexPopov- OK, but as I said, it was a proof-of-concept kind of thing, you'll probably want to tweak it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested:

```
Plot[(2/5)*x + 3/5, {x, 0, 20}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[.5, 20, 1], Range[.5, 20, 1]}, AspectRatio -> .5,
  ImageSize -> 500, 
 Prolog -> 
  RegionPlot[
    Floor[(2/5)*x + 3/5] - .0 <= y <= Ceiling[(2/5)*x + 3/5] + .0, {x,
      0, 20}, {y, 0, 10}, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> .5, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2]][[1]]]
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways...

Comment: I posted an extension of this as an answer below.  If you would prefer that I make it an edit to your answer I can do that instead.

Comment: Good lord no, like I said in my comment to the OP, it was a proof-of-concept that ended up being useful to them. You've turned it into something actually usable for generalized cases, certainly worthy of it's own answer and credit!

Comment: Okay, cool. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt to package rasher's method into something a bit more easily reused:

```
SetAttributes[plotWithGrid, HoldAll]

plotWithGrid[fn_, {v_, x_, X_}, opts : OptionsPattern[Plot]] :=
 Module[{gf, plot, fill},
  gf[lo_, hi_] := Range[Floor[lo, 1/2], Ceiling[hi, 1/2]];
  plot = Plot[fn, {v, x, X}, GridLines -> {gf, gf}, opts];
  fill = PlotRange[plot] /. {_, {y_, Y_}} :>
    RegionPlot[⌊fn⌋ ≤ yy ≤ ⌈fn⌉,
      {v,  x - 0.1 (X - x), X + 0.1 (X - x)},
      {yy, y - 0.1 (Y - y), Y + 0.1 (Y - y)},
      Axes -> False,
      Frame -> False,
      PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2],
      PlotPoints -> 120
    ];
  Show[plot, Prolog -> fill[[1]]]
 ]
```

Test:

```
plotWithGrid[7 Sinc[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a general setting for shifting the grindlines to I used the option for specifying manual gridlines and used this: `GridLines -> {{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5}, {-0.5, -1.5, -2.5, -3.5, -4.5, - 5.5}}`.

Comment: Try `{Range[.5, 11.5, .5], Reverse@Range[-5.5, -.5, .5]}`