# Plotting curves with different filling styles and gridlines?

Tags: plotting, filling

Here's a plot of some lines with different styles of filling and one gridline displayed:

```
LogLogPlot[{10^1 x^(-4/5), 10^15 x^(-4/5), 10^30 x^(-4/5)}, {x, 1, 
  10^40}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^20}, Automatic}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> Axis, 2 -> {1}, 3 -> {2}, 3 -> Top}, 
 GridLines -> {{10^10}, None}]
```

but if I want to specify different fill colors, I get a gridline that is covered by the fill instead of the standard behavior:

```
LogLogPlot[{10^1 x^(-4/5), 10^15 x^(-4/5), 10^30 x^(-4/5)}, {x, 1, 
  10^40}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^20}, Automatic}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, LightOrange}, 2 -> {{1}, LightBlue}, 
   3 -> {{2}, LightGreen}, 3 -> {Top, LightRed}}, 
 GridLines -> {{10^10}, None}]
```

[image]

I've been reading through the docs on [`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) and [`FillingStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FillingStyle.html) but they don't seem to cover this use case.

How can I specify multiple colors, fills, and gridlines, and show the gridlines normally on top of the solid fill colors?

Comment: Use the option `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`?

Comment: Possibly related [28025](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28025/how-to-draw-grid-lines-on-top-of-a-plot).

Comment: @kguler Thanks for the heads up on the undocumented option. Unfortunately, I get error message LogLogPlot::optx (unknown option) when I try to set GridLinesInFront->True.

Comment: you need to use it as `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`, i.e., as the value of the option `Method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question [has been answered elsewere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28027/20144).

As @kglr helpfully pointed out in the comments, the undocumented option:

```
Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}
```

will cause the gridlines to display over the fill and styled curves:

```
LogLogPlot[{10^1 x^(-4/5), 10^15 x^(-4/5), 10^30 x^(-4/5)}, {x, 1, 
  10^40}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10^20}, Automatic}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Axis, LightOrange}, 2 -> {{1}, LightBlue}, 
   3 -> {{2}, LightGreen}, 3 -> {Top, LightRed}}, 
 GridLines -> {{10^10}, None}, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}]
```

[image]