# Why is ListContourPlot so slow?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

The process of `ListContourPlot[]` or `ListDensityPlot[]` is extremely slow comparing to Matlab's `contour()`. Why? Is it possible to speed it up? I prefer `ListDensityPlot[]` but plotting of an array of 512x512 elements takes about 5 min (several seconds with `contour()` in Matlab).

**EDIT**

To be more specific:
I have a regular square grid of `(x,y)` coordinates, `x = y = -5*^-7 ... 5*^-7`, and a square grid of function values in range `[0,0.05]`. To plot these data I tried `ListDensityPlot[{{x1,y1,f1},{x2,y2,f2},...,{xn,yn,fn}}]` but it's very slow (several minutes, rescaling doesn't help). `DensityPlot[Interpolate[...]]` is much faster but the image quality deteriorates by interpolation. I like `ArrayPlot[]`, it's fast and image looks nice, but I loose any information about coordinates.  I need to simply visualize points without any changes but keep (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: It shouldn't take that long, can you post the code that generates the data, or is it too long?  Is the data in the form of an $n \times n$ array, or in the form of `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2},.......{xn, yn, zn}}`?

Comment: It really does. The generation is a bit long but data are stored, so I actually use `ListDensityPlot[{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2},.......{x262144, y262144, z262144}}]`.

Comment: Are the data points in a regular grid?  Or are they randomly spaced throughout the grid?  If they are regular, then you are **much** better off reshaping it so that you have an $n \times n$ array of z values only.  For some reason that plots much better.

Comment: Another option that is probably faster is to do this, `intfunc=Interpolation[data]; DensityPlot[ intfunc[x, y], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, options]`  where `data` is your data and `options` are all the options you use with `ListDensityPlot`

Comment: By any chance, is your data such that the scale for the z-axis much different than it's y and x scales?  If so, that could also be a source of the trouble, it is a known bug

Comment: There is some discussion [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27203/listdensityplot-performance-when-scaling-axes)

Comment: Further issues, possibly relevant: [ListContourPlot and ListContourPlot3D use better interpolation for arrays of values than for lists of tuples](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98145/27951), and depending on your version, you may be running into a bug that existed up to version 10.3: [Terrifying performance decrease for contour/density plots in v10.1 -> 10.3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99255/27951).

Comment: Thank you all for useful advises! I tried `DensityPlot[Interpolation[...]]` which is much faster indeed, but image quality is very bad with interpolation. Much better quality is achieved with `ArrayPlot[]` which i like a lot, but I loose informations about `(x,y)` coordinates. I need to simply visualize points on regular grid without any interpolation but keep `(x,y)` coordinates.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This comes up quite often here - *Mathematica* simply does a **much** better job of making 2D plots when the data is an $n\times n$ array of z-values than it does when the data is an $n^2 \times 3$ list of `{x, y, z}` tuples. I think it uses different interpolation algorithms.

If the data is on a regular grid, then there is absolutely no reason to use the tuples form, since you can specify the x and y ranges using [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html).  Here is an example, with a larger list of data than in the OP,

```
testdata1 = 
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, 
     Sin[x - 2 y] Cos[
       2 x + y]}, {x, -π, π, .01}, {y, -π, π, .01}], 
   1];

Dimensions@testdata1
(* {395641, 3} *)
```

If I use `ListDensityPlot` on the data in this format, it takes 81 seconds on my machine (`ListContourPlot` takes a bit longer),

```
ListDensityPlot[testdata1, ImageSize -> 400] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

If, however, I restructure the data using `Partition` (and `Transpose` to keep the x and y axes in the same spot), then it only takes about 4 seconds,

```
testdata2 = Transpose[Partition[testdata1[[All, 3]], 629]];
ListDensityPlot[testdata2, ImageSize -> 400, 
  DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Exact same output, in much less time.

You can get a similar plot with `ArrayPlot`, although it doesn't make the tick marks look very nice.  You have to reverse the data to account for the reversal that automatically happens with `ArrayPlot`,

```
ArrayPlot[Reverse@testdata2, 
  ColorFunction -> "M10DefaultDensityGradient", 
  DataRange -> {{-π, π}, {-π, π}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameTicks -> All, ImageSize -> 500(*,DataReversed\[Rule]{True,
  False}*)] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

This is the fastest non-interpolating option.  You can get away from the ugly tick labels if you use the `CustomTicks` package, part of the [`SciDraw` package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/beta/).  If you do the above plot using `FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks, StripTickLabels@LinTicks}, {LinTicks, StripTickLabels@LinTicks}}` then it comes out looking decent.

Another workaround is to use `Interpolation`, and it is faster, but it's usually better to work with the data itself.  And to get the same quality, you often have to use a high value for `PlotPoints`,

```
func = Interpolation[testdata1];
DensityPlot[func[x, y], {x, -π, π}, {y, -π, π}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotPoints -> 100] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: So the middle method is the one I'm advocating (`ListDenistyPlot[testdata2,DataRange->....]`, not the last one.  But you can get there with `ArrayPlot` as well, but I think the tickmarks are uglier.

Comment: As to the ticks issue, you can also draw a blank density plot and then show it with the array plot: `Show[DensityPlot[False, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, {y, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> 400], (*ArrayPlot[...]*)]`

Comment: @JasonB. How would you do this if the data is not `n^2 x 3` but `n x m x 3`? I tried doing this by using the largest of two, let's say `n`: `Transpose[Partition[testdata1[[All, 3]], 629]]` but the resulting image is not identical to the original. I have a mirror symmetry along the `0`.
Edit: It's because my data range runs from 5 to -5. So I probably need to sort that.