# Performance in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

Consider an array of triplets:
`specup={{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...{xn,yn,zn}}`. 
The dimensions for specup are `{1506006, 3}`. The ranges for the variables are as follows: `x->{0,5},y->{-14,14},z->{0,1300}`. The idea is to do a density plot where z dictates the color. I use

```
ListDensityPlot[
 specup
 , ColorFunction -> {Black, Blue, Cyan, Green, Yellow, Orange, White}
 , PlotLegends -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 , InterpolationOrder -> 1
 ]
```

However, due to the sheer number of entries the plot never finishes, I gave it 2 plus hours. Is there a way to optimize the plotting?

Data is available at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yDtyzjf4GgurIE0GGCkH5qAQvLuNixjn

Comment: Are your `{x,y,z}` points a regular grid?  If so you would be better off rearranging the data from a list of `{x, y, z}` tuples into a 3-dimensional array of `z` values.  `ListDensityPlot` just handles this input format better.  Once you've rearranged the data, if you find it is still slow because of the size of the data, you can use [`ArrayResample`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayResample.html) to make the data size more manageable.

Comment: So the grid I have is  constant x, dy, z. It goes down the line of y values then shifts x and goes again. Wont I lose the information of x and y in the 3-dimensional array? For example {x1,y1,z1} -> TestArray[[1,1]], which returns z1. However I wont be able to get the x,y coordinates or am I wrong in the understanding?

Comment: Did you check the `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` option?  Access to the data could allow us to test a few things.

Comment: @ rhermans Data has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to avoid sending such large amounts of data to a `ListPlot` command, because it does not by default do **any** downsampling.  The size of the resulting `Graphics` expression will contain every point you feed it, and if you feed it a million points then the front end will have a hard time rendering it.

First import the data,

```
data = Import["~/Downloads/specup.csv"];
```

Next delete those elements with duplicate `{x,y}` values,

```
data2 = DeleteDuplicatesBy[data, Most];

Dimensions /@ {data, data2}
(* {{1506006, 3}, {1503501, 3}} *)
```

Next, convert the array into a matrix of `z` values instead of a list of `{x, y, z}` tuples.  *Mathematica* will **always** plot the matrix better than the list of tuples, this is described in more detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109718/9490) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98145/9490).

```
array = Module[
    {
        xvalues = AssociationThread[#->Range[Length@#]]&@Union[data2[[All,1]]],
        yvalues = AssociationThread[#->Range[Length@#]]&@Union[data2[[All,2]]],
        res = ConstantArray[0, {3001, 501}]
    },
    Scan[
        (res[[xvalues@#[[1]],yvalues@#[[2]]]]=#[[3]])&,
        data2
    ];
    res
];
```

Now you still have way too much data to plot efficiently, but it's very easy to downsample your data

```
data3 = ArrayResample[array, {300, 300}];

ListDensityPlot[data3, PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 5}, {-14, 14}}]
```

[image]

I may have gotten the x and y ranges backwards, but that's an easy fix.  You can adjust the second argument of `ArrayResample` to increase the quality of the resulting plot.

I should point out that you could resample your data without first converting to an array, by using `Interpolation`.  But I do not think this is worth the trouble, and I also suspect it will give a lower quality result.

Comment: How did you get the numbers in res?

Comment: I had a typo there, where no data was actually assigned to `array`.  If you look at the module inside of the definition for `array`,  I scan over all the elements of `data2`, and assign them to a `Part` of `res`.  That definition may be too terse, I could expand it to be more readable.

Comment: @ Jason B. If you could, please. Im going over the code now, trying it out.Thank you.

Comment: I know understand the reasoning. Suppose I have another array where z is negative, is there a way I can do this to get BOTH datasets in the same plot? I tried making a separate array but I realized I cant Join the arrays.

Comment: @GiovanniBaez - Do the two datasets cover the same x/y range?  when you combine them, do they make a regular grid?  Or are they two separate regions?  If they combine to make a regular grid, then you combine the datasets first, and *then* convert to an array.  If they are separate regions, then how do you want to combine them graphically?

Comment: Another thing is that if you are generating the data yourself, you can just generate it as an array to start with.  If you are getting the data from another source, then you do need to do some preprocessing work.  Any more talk here and we should move to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79117/listdensityplot