# Convert ConvexHull to Inequality

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh

I have the following convex hull.

```
P0={0,0,0};
P1={1,0,0};
P2={0,1,0};
P3={0,0,1};

ConvexHullMesh[{P0,P1,P2,P3}]
```

Now I want the region algebraically as equality of the convex hull generated, in this case `x+y+z<1&&x>0&&y>0&&z>0`.
Is there any automatic way to get it from Mathematica by converting the convex hull generated as a region and then convert it into inequality?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
chm = ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P1, P2, P3}]; 

ClearAll[regFunc]

regFunc[{x, y, z}] := FullSimplify @ RegionMember[Rationalize @
    MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[chm, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞], 3][[1]]] @ {x, y, z}

regFunc @ {x, y, z}
```

> ```
>  x + y + z <= 1 && z >= 0 && y >= 0 && x >= 0
> ```

Also

```
dm = DelaunayMesh[{P0, P1, P2, P3}];

ClearAll[regFunc2]

regFunc2[{x_, y_, z_}] := FullSimplify @
   RegionMember[Rationalize @ First @ MeshPrimitives[dm, 3]] @ {x, y, z};

regFunc2 @ {x, y, z}
```

> ```
>  x + y + z <= 1 && z >= 0 && y >= 0 && x >= 0
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Just another question: Can this be done for a 4-d convex hull? Of course, Mathematica cannot evaluate the convex hull for a 4-d case. But is there any way to get the inequality representation of the convex hull?
The type of convex hull I work with has 5 points for a 4-d case and so is very simple. Say for example {0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}, {0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1}. Is there any way to get it just like the 3d case you showed in Mathematica itself?

Comment: @SumitBanik, thank you for the accept. Don't know how the nD case can be handled.

Comment: Alright.Thanks a lot

Comment: An nD example can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113976/4346).

Comment: When I several convex hulls defined in an array R[i], where say

Comment: @Sumit, if I understand correctly, you can use the method above to get a region function  for each of your several convex hulls, then you can combine them  with `Or` to get  a single region function.

Comment: @kglr Sorry the earlier comment was incomplete.
When I have several convex hulls defined in an array R[i], where say
R[1]= ConvexHullMesh[{P0, P1, P2, P3}];
Now I run a do loop to find the region inequality at once for all convex hull in the array R[i] using the code.
Do[regFunc[i][{x, y, z}] := FullSimplify @ RegionMember[Rationalize @
    MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[R[i], MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]], 3][[1]]] @ {x, y, z},{i,1,16}];
regFunc[1]@{x,y,z}
But this code is not working

Comment: @SumitBanik, If you put `ClearAll[regFunc]` before `Do[...]` and it still does not work, please  update your post (or post a new question) with a smaller version of your array `R` (with 2 regions instead of 16).

Comment: @kglr. Thanks for your comments. I tried it but it didn't help. So I made a new post with two problems https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223985/convert-convexhull-in-a-array-to-inequality.