# Convert ConvexHull in a array to Inequality

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

This question is in continuation with the previous post [Convert ConvexHull to Inequality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223943/convert-convexhull-to-inequality)

There are two problems that I faced.
Suppose we have two or more convex hull defined using an array R[i], like

```
P[0]={0,0,0};P[1]={1,0,0};P[2]={0,1,0};P[3]={0,0,1};P[4]={-1,-1,-1};P[5]={-1,0,-1};
P[6]={0,-1,-1};
R[1]=ConvexHullMesh[{P[0],P[1],P[2],P[3]}];
R[2]=ConvexHullMesh[{P[0],P[1],P[2],P[4]}];
```

Now to find the region inequality at once for all convex hull in the array I use a do loop as

```
    Do[regFunc[i][{x, y, z}] := FullSimplify @ RegionMember[Rationalize @ MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[R[i],  MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]], 3][[1]]] @ {x, y, z},{i,1,2}];
regFunc[1]@{x,y,z}
```

But this gives error and so I have to manually write the whole code for each convex hull. 
Secondly, I want the region as a open region. This means that I want > or < not >= or <= . This is because later I will calculate region intersection using ImplicitRegion, where due to >= or <= the regions seem to intersect at the boundaries, which I don't want. Any possible way to do it in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy part of the question: (1) Use `regFunc[i][{x_, y_, z_}]` (not `regFunc[i][{x, y, z}]`) when you define `regFunc`, (2) Use `With[{i = i}, ...]` to inject the value of `i` on the right-hand-side expression:

```
Do[With[{i = i}, 
   regFunc[i][{x_, y_, z_}] := FullSimplify@
     RegionMember[
       Rationalize@
        MeshPrimitives[
          DiscretizeRegion[R[i], MaxCellMeasure -> ∞], 3][[1]]]@{x, y, z}],
   {i, 1, 2}];

Column @ {regFunc[1]@{x, y, z}, regFunc[2]@{x, y, z}}
```

[image]

Not sure about the second part, but maybe you can do this:

```
{regFunc[1]@{x, y, z}, regFunc[2]@{x, y, z}} /. 
     {LessEqual -> Less, GreaterEqual -> Greater} // Column
```

[image]