# Using Third Party Package

Tags: packages

I am new to mathematica. I wish to use the third Party Code QHull in mathematica. The code was written in C and compiled into .exe. Are there any settings  that I have to do in Mathematica so that I may use the compiled code ? Currently I am not able to call the functions from mathematica.

Comment: Welcome! Please search the site for existing threads on “qhull“, and see if these already cover your request. If you have problems with your codr, post that here to facilitate helping.

Comment: Look into [(113492)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113492/27951) and [(13437)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13437/27951).