# How to find intersection of higher dimensional convex hull?

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh

I have often used `ConvexHullMesh` to obtain a convex hull for 2-d and 3-d points. But when I try to find it for 4-D points I encounter error even for simple cases.

```
ConvexHullMesh[{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0}]
```

The above code gives no result. Is there any way to construct 4-d and higher dimensional convex hull in Mathematica itself using external packages? My main purpose is to check whether there is an intersection among several higher dimension convex hulls. Will `RegionIntersection` work for 4-d cases as well?

Comment: Perhaps something in [this prior MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113492/how-to-generate-higher-dimensional-convex-hull) will be useful.

Comment: Thanks. I read it before. But do you know whether using qhull it is possible to find intersections of several convex hulls?

Comment: That I do not know.