# DelauneyMesh in 4d and higher

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Is there any way to find the `DelauneyMesh` in 4D (or higher)? Its documentation implies that it should be possible *"A Delaunay mesh consists of intervals (in 1D), triangles (in 2D), tetrahedra (in 3D), and n-dimensional simplices (in nD)."* But then it fails without error (and there are no 4D examples anywhere). I guess it does not actually work for 4D or higher? Are there any user-made algorithms out there. Is there a fundamental obstacle to making this? (Scales too terrible with n?)

Comment: [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org) can do this, so one might consider a way to interface Qhull and *Mathematica* to generate the required triangulation. See [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113492) as well.

Comment: I would like to see this too but for 3D Voronoi. I suggested it to Wolfram back in v11 but it has not been implemented. You could use `Nearest` to get a `NearestFunction` and build it up yourself.