# Image processing: extracting ordered contour

Tags: image-processing, computational-geometry

Continuing the question
[How to extract the edge from a set of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/how-to-extract-the-edge-from-a-set-of-points) and its answer by Simon Woods,
I would like to ask if there is a way to extract the boundary of 
[image]

obtained as

```
ToExpression@Import@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=741qaDt2";
boundary = Complement[spiel, Intersection @@ 
    Outer[Plus, {{0, 1}, {0, -1}, {1, 0}, {-1, 0}}, spiel, 1]];
```

ordered in such a way that

```
ListPlot[boundary,Joined->True]
```

would give a polygon outlining the shape? The points extracted the way they are in the answer are not ordered along the boundary:
[image: not ordered points]

It would be even better to know if it is possible with `MorphometricComponents[]`, because images I am working on look like that:
[image: typical image]

With `MorphometricComponents[]` one can extract perimeter lenghts, baricenters and whatever he likes for the components, but not the ordered perimeter points themselves.

So the question is if there is a way to do that? Just to be clear: for each region in the picture, I would like to have the ordered coordinates of the points of the boundary `boundary={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}` such that `ListPlot[boundary,Joined->True]` would give polygons outlining the shapes.

Comment: This is probably not going to solve your problem completely, but it's good to know about `FindCurvePath` (look it up)

Comment: @Szabolcs Indeed, that is a quick solution. Using `ListPlot[boundary[[FindCurvePath[boundary][[1]]]], Joined -> True]` I get an ordered curve. The question remains about `MorphometricComponents[]`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't always find the "right" ordering, and sometimes it returns several disjoint curves.  So it's probably not good as a general solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs Agreed. The idea is that you know how the curve goes when you have the original image. And I'm thinking about a way not to lose this information. When you come to the `boundary` the way it is described, you have already lost it.

Comment: Maybe a TSP? Might not be fully robust, but should probably take you most of the way...

Comment: Also, in future, please include the extracted list of points in the question (I've added it this time). It's less work for someone who wants to answer this question than to have to read the other one, grab the data and use Simon's answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not directly possible to compute the outline of objects with the provided morphological image processing functions. I use the outline of connected components very often too, mostly for visualising, but I think something like this should really be included in `ComponentMeasurements`.

Since you know that the distance between outline pixel will always be smaller equal `Sqrt[2]` in a 4 neighbourhood and that your outline pixel will always be a closed contour, you can easily implement this functionality by yourself. With an eroded and padded version of your image (to make more objects):

```
img = ImagePad[Erosion[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmKw2.png"], 1], 5]
```

the implementation of such an algorithm is straight forward. Calculate the morphological perimeter with erosion/dilation or with `MorphologicalPerimeter` to get all the boundary pixel. For one object, you start at any boundary pixel, exclude it from the rest and find the next closest pixel. Then this pixel is your new starting point and you repeat until there are no pixels left. If you want a closed line contour, don't forget to append your very first pixel to the final sorted list:

```
createPath[pts_] := 
 Append[NestList[
    Function[data, With[{fst = First[data], rst = Last[data]},
      {Extract[rst, #], Delete[rst, #]} &[
       Nearest[rst -> Automatic, fst, 1]]
      ]], {First[pts], Rest[pts]}, Length[pts] - 1][[All, 1]], 
  First[pts]]
```

Then you need a small wrapper function to calculate the morphological perimeter and convert them into pixel positions

```
extractPaths[img_Image] := 
 With[{masks = ComponentMeasurements[MorphologicalComponents[
       MorphologicalPerimeter[img, CornerNeighbors -> False]], "Mask"][[All, 2]]},
  createPath[Position[Transpose@Reverse@Normal[#], 1]] & /@ masks
]
```

Now you can use `extractPaths` to get a list of all object outlines:

```
HighlightImage[img, Flatten[extractPaths[img], 1]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: A good solution, thank you! Just one more question: do you see a way how to assure that all the contours are passed in the same direction: clockwise or counterclockwise?

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be posed as a [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), where we have a salesman starting at a city (or a point) and has to visit every other city once while minimizing his total distance.

```
pts = boundary[[Last@FindShortestTour[boundary, Method -> "CCA", 
    DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]]]; 
Show[
    ListPlot[spiel, PlotStyle -> Gray],
    ListLinePlot[pts, PlotStyle -> Red]
]
```

[image]

I'm not sure if this is guaranteed to work under all circumstances (especially in regions with a "pinch" zone, like the figure 8), but for the examples shown in your blob, it should work.