# Calendar view outline

Tags: graphics, date-and-time, regions

How to compute the outline of a calendar month like this [D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318).

(D3 is a functional language built on JavaScript developed at Stanford and used by New York Times to deploy interactive graphics.)

```
days = <| DayRange[DateObject[{2014, 10, 5}], 
     DateObject[{2014, 10, 11}]] // Map[DayName] // 
   MapIndexed [#1 -> First[#2] &] |>

(* <|Sunday -> 1, Monday -> 2, Tuesday -> 3, Wednesday -> 4, 
 Thursday -> 5, Friday -> 6, Saturday -> 7|> *)
```

Day positions for Oct 2014:

```
october2014 = <| 
    DayRange[DateObject[{2014, 10, 1}], 
      DateObject[{2014, 10, 31}]] //  
     MapIndexed[#1 -> {days[DayName[#1]], -1 - 
          Quotient[-days[DayName[#1]] + First[#2], 7]} &] |> // 
   Dataset;
```

Individual day `Rectangles` give shape to the month though because they overlap the grid looks somewhat ragged:

```
{october2014[Values, Rectangle[# - {1, 1}, #] & /* RegionBoundary] // 
   Normal,
  october2014[KeyMap[Normal /* (#[[3]] &)]] // Normal // Normal // 
   Map[Text[First[#], Last[#] - {1/2, 1/2}] &] } // Graphics
```

[image]

But how to compute (not only show graphically) the boundary of the month as a whole?

```
october2014[Values /* RegionUnion /* RegionBoundary, 
   Rectangle[# - {1, 1}, #] &] // Normal // DiscretizeRegion
```

[image]

The desired answer is a closed `Line` specified by the corner points of the boundary only. This is a special case of [simplifying polyhedral region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61019/simplify-polyhedral-regions-like-interval) (currently no answers), but will accept any method.

The correct answer for above is:

```
Line[{{0, -5}, {6, -5}, {6, -4}, {7, -4}, {7, 0}, {3,0}, {3, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, -5}}]
```

Comment: seen [Lunchtime Playground >> time series as calendar heat map](http://mathgis.blogspot.com.tr/2010/01/charting-time-series-as-calendar-heat.html)?

Comment: I believe you can use [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45085/5) of mine to get the outline as a closed `Line` (just feed the points to `Line`).

Comment: @rm-rf, in trying to replicate your answer I can't Import that data: It's a CSV but whose first row is: `{"spiel = {{186", " -89}", " {186", " -88}", " {185", " -89}", " \
{187", " -89}", " {186", " -90}", " {186", " "}`... Can you post your solution? But see my comment to Juhno below re expected format.

Comment: As an FYI Yu Sung Chang has posted interactive calendar code somewhere ...maybe here, maybe wolfram community, maybe demonstrations ...do not recall but it is fully interactive so as to select dates for calculations.

Comment: Perhaps instead of building the rectangles you can build lines, and only keep the vertices that appear an odd number of times?

Comment: Such as `october2014[Values, {# - {1, 1}, #, # - {0, 1}, # - {1, 0}} &][
 Apply[Join] /* Counts /* Select[OddQ] /* Keys /* sort /* Line /* 
  Graphics]`

Comment: Sorry, `sort = #[[Last@FindShortestTour[#, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]]] &;`

Comment: @alancalvitti Sorry, I've lost access to Mathematica and until I get around to buying a copy, I won't be able to answer. I believe you just need the definition of `boundary` for my answer and this part is in the question.

Comment: @Rojo, nice, in other words, corner points are on 1 or 3 rectangles. Why not post as answer? I'm adapting it to avoid computing the tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method inspired by Rojo's that uses `VectorAngle` to select corner points, based on their angle with adjoining points along the boundary. This avoids the traveling salesman.

**Generalizing to any month:**

```
days = <|Sunday -> 1, Monday -> 2, Tuesday -> 3, Wednesday -> 4, Thursday -> 5, Friday -> 6, Saturday -> 7|>;
```

.

```
daySpan[DateObject[{y_, m_}]] := 
      DayRange[{y, m}, DatePlus[{y, m}, {1, "Month"}]] // Drop[#, -1] &;
```

.

```
dayPositionAssociation[DateObject[{y_, m_}]] := daySpan[DateObject[{y, m}]] // 
    MapIndexed[#1 -> {days[DayName[#1]], -1 - 
         Quotient[First[#2] - days[DayName[#1]], 7]} &] // Association;
```

.

```
dayRegion[p_List] := 
      MeshRegion[{p, p - {1, 0}, p - {1, 1}, p - {0, 1}}, Polygon[{1, 2, 3, 4}]];
```

Given neighboring points {p,q,r} along the boundary, VectorAngle[p-q,q-r] is either 0 or Pi/2. The list of MeshCoordinates needs to be wrapped cyclically:

```
   selectCornerPoints[pts_List] :=  Prepend[pts, Last@pts] // Append[#, First@pts] & // 
     Partition[#, 3, 1] & // 
    Select[ VectorAngle[#[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[3]] - #[[2]]] != 0 &] // 
   Map[#[[2]] &];
```

**Oct 2014:**

```
boundaryPts = dayPositionAssociation[DateObject[{2014, 10}]] // Map[dayRegion] // 
    Values // RegionUnion // MeshCoordinates // Round;
```

.

```
boundaryPts // selectCornerPoints
(* {{0, -5}, {0, -1}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {7, 0}, {7, -4}, {6, -4}, {6, -5}} *)
```

**2014 outline**

```
 Table[m -> (dayPositionAssociation[DateObject[{2014, m}]] // 
             Map[dayRegion] // Values // RegionUnion // 
          MeshCoordinates // Round // 
        selectCornerPoints // {Gray, Polygon[#], PointSize -> 0.05, 
         Red, Map[Point, #]} & // Graphics),
   {m, 1, 12}] // Partition[#, 3] & // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

```
ClearAll[mpbmdcg,ljr]; 
mpbmdcg[k_]:= Composition[MeshPrimitives[#,k]&, BoundaryMesh, DiscretizeGraphics, Graphics];
ljr = Composition[Line, Join[#, {#[[1]]}]&, Replace[#,Line[{a_,b_}]:>a, {0, Infinity}]&];

poly = First@mpbmdcg[2]@(Rectangle/@(-1+Normal[october2014[Values]]));
fastdesc= FullSimplify[ Reduce[ 
         Region`RegionProperty[Rationalize/@poly, {x, y}, "FastDescription"][[1,2]],{x,y}]]
(*(0 <= x < 3 && -5 <= y <= -1)||(3 <= x <= 6 && -5 <= y <= 0)||(6 <  x <= 7 && -4 <= y <= 0) *)

rectangles = Rectangle@@@(Transpose/@((fastdesc/. And|Or->List)/.  Inequality[a_,__,b_]:>{a,b}));

lines = ljr @ mpbmdcg[1] @ rectangles
(*  Line[{{6., 0.}, {3.,   0.}, {3., -1.}, {0., -1.}, {0., -5.}, 
          {3., -5.}, {6., -5.}, {6.,  4.}, {7., -4.}, {7., 0.}, {6., 0.}}]*)
```

---

**Original post:**

Junho answers the specific question re the outline of the month grid.

Here I make a few minor changes (to remove dependence on the `Calendar` package by using V9 date/time functions) in ragfield's  code ([available at LunchTime Playground](http://mathgis.blogspot.com.tr/2010/01/charting-time-series-as-calendar-heat.html)) 
which provides a full-fledged calendar heat map.

First few lines on sources:

[image]

```
dayindex = {Sunday -> 1, Monday -> 2, Tuesday -> 3, Wednesday -> 4, 
            Thursday -> 5, Friday -> 6, Saturday -> 7};
monthstart[month_, year_] := DayName[{year, month, 1}] /. dayindex
dayspermonth[month_, year_] := DayCount[{year,month,1},DatePlus[{year, month, 1}, {{1, "Month"}}]]
monthlayout[month_, year_] := Partition[Range[dayspermonth[month, year]], 7, 7, 
                              {monthstart[month, year], 1}, ""]
```

Generate month grid:

```
startingweek[month_, year_] := Ceiling[(DayCount[{year, 1, 1}, {year, month, 1}] + 
     monthstart[1, year])/7.0]
monthgrid[month_, year_] := Module[{cd, cds, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, shift}, 
  shift = startingweek[month, year]; cd = monthlayout[month, year]; 
  cds = Position[cd, x_ /; x != ""]; cds[[All, 2]] = 7 - cds[[All, 2]];
  cds[[All, 1]] = cds[[All, 1]] - 1 + shift; 
  p1 = {shift, cds[[1, 2]] + 1}; p2 = {shift, 0}; 
  p3 = {Max[cds[[All, 1]]], 0}; p4 = Last[cds]; 
  p5 = Last[cds] + {1, 0}; p6 = {p5[[1]], 7}; p7 = {shift + 1, 7}; 
  p8 = p1 + {1, 0}; 
  Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Gray], Rectangle[#] & /@ cds, Thick, 
    Line[{p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p1}]}]]

Labeled[Show[monthgrid[10, 2014]], 
 Style[DateString[{2014, 10}, {"MonthName", " ", "Year"}], "Section",  Purple], Top]
```

[image]

Generate year grid:

```
yeargrid[year_, opts : OptionsPattern[Show]] := Show[Table[monthgrid[i, year], {i, 1, 12}], opts]

Column[Labeled[yeargrid[#, ImageSize -> 500], Style[#,"Subsection"], Top] & /@ {2012, 2013, 2014}]
```

[image]

Use with data:

```
year = 2013; stock = "AAPL";
bg = yeargrid[year];
price = FinancialData[stock, {{year, 1, 1}, {year, 12, 31}}];
DateListPlot[price, Filling -> Axis, Joined -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> stock <> " " <> ToString[year]]
```

[image]

Some preps:

```
(* color the data *)
colors = Blend[{Green, Red}, #] & /@ Rescale[price[[All, 2]]];

(* calculate xy postion for the each date *)
rectposition[{y_, m_, d_}] := Module[{lx, ly}, 
  lx = Ceiling[(DayCount[{y, 1, 1}, {y, m, d}] + monthstart[1, y])/7.0]; 
          ly = 7 - DayName[{y, m, d}] /. dayindex; {lx, ly}]

(* generate legend *)
q = DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 0.1}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   FrameTicks -> None, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Red}, #] &), 
   PlotRangePadding -> None];
l = Show[q, ImageSize -> 200, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {{{0, Min[price[[All, 2]]]}, 
                   {1, Max[price[[All, 2]]]}},  None}}];

(* generate label *)
lt = Graphics[{Text[Style[#[[1]], Medium, Black], {-1, 7 - #[[2]] + 0.5}]} & /@ dayindex];
```

... final steps:

```
cq = Table[{FaceForm[colors[[i]]], 
    Rectangle[rectposition[price[[i, 1]]]]}, {i, 1, Length[price]}];
sg = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], cq}];

Show[lt, sg, bg, 
 PlotLabel -> Style[stock <> " " <> ToString[year], "Section"],
 Frame -> True, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[White], FrameLabel -> l, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image]

Comment: @kguler, In March 2013 there are only 7 corner points, but your algorithm outputs 8. Is it a simple matter of taking `Union` of the `p1` ...`p8` in `monthgrid`?

Comment: @alan, `Union` is a good idea. But I think Junho's solution is more robust and straightforward. As is `ljr` works when `fastdesc` terms are all `Inequality`s; it needs more work to account for other patterns in `fastdesc`.

Comment: @kguler, on review, 8 points are generally distinct but 1 may not be a corner point (eg 1 or 2 months in any given year), then  `Union` would not delete the non-corner point.

Comment: Packaged your code: https://github.com/kmisiunas/PlotCalendar

Answer (score 6):

This is your codes.

```
days = <|DayRange[DateObject[{2014, 10, 5}], 
      DateObject[{2014, 10, 11}]] // Map[DayName] // 
    MapIndexed[#1 -> First[#2] &]|>;
october2014 = <|
    DayRange[DateObject[{2014, 10, 1}], DateObject[{2014, 10, 31}]] //
      MapIndexed[#1 -> {days[DayName[#1]], -1 - 
          Quotient[-days[DayName[#1]] + First[#2], 7]} &]|> // 
   Dataset;
```

I made `RectangleRegionSimplify` like this as referred to [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61107/16245)

```
lastUnion[coo_] := 
 Flatten[Replace[SplitBy [ coo, Last], {f_, ___, l_} -> {f, l}, 1], 1]
firstUnion[coo_] := 
 Flatten[Replace[SplitBy [ coo, First], {f_, ___, l_} -> {f, l}, 1], 1]
RectangleRegionSimplify[p__] := Module[{pts, rst},
  pts = MeshPrimitives[
     BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
      DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion@p], MaxCellMeasure -> \[Infinity]],
      2][[1, 1]];
  rst = Append[pts, First[pts]];
  rst = N[Rationalize[Chop[rst, 10^-6]], 5];
  rst // firstUnion // lastUnion // Rationalize // N // Line
  ]
```

Now you can check your code with this.

```
pri = MeshPrimitives[
   october2014[Values, Rectangle[# - {1, 1}, #] &] // Normal // 
    BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics, 2];
pri1 = RectangleRegionSimplify[pri]
pri2 = october2014[KeyMap[Normal /* (#[[3]] &)]] // Normal // Normal //
    Map[Text[First[#], Last[#] - {1/2, 1/2}] &];
Graphics[{pri1, PointSize[Large], Red, Point @@ pri1, pri2}]
```

> `Line[{{3., -1.}, {0., -1.}, {0., -5.}, {6., -5.}, {6., -4.}, {7., \
>   -4.}, {7., 0.}, {3., 0.}, {3., -1.}}]`
>
> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: "...compute (not only show graphically)...". Output should be `Line[{p1,...,pn}]` where `pk` are the calendar's corner points only.

Comment: That yields the entire grid of lines. The correct answer is: `Line[{{0, -5}, {6, -5}, {6, -4}, {7, -4}, {7, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, -5}}]`.

Comment: Your latest edit still has too many points, eg: `{..., {2., -1.}, {1., -1.},...}`

Comment: @alancalvitti  Would you check the answer.

Comment: +1, your method tests ok on all months in 2014, thanks. I also tested by deleting an "internal" day 2014-10-14, which broke: `MeshPrimitives::cnorep: There is no simple cell representation for the specified cells of the BoundaryMeshRegion`. That's fine as it's not a real calendar month, but I would like to investigate further & compare to kguler.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of building the rectangles you can build lines, and only keep the vertices that appear an odd number of times?
Such as

```
sort = #[[Last@FindShortestTour[#, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]]] &
october2014[Values, {# - {1, 1}, #, # - {0, 1}, # - {1, 0}} &][ 
   Apply[Join] /* Counts /* Select[OddQ] /* Keys /* sort /* Line /* Graphics]
```

Comment: Sorry, can't build a more proper answer now

Comment: How is this not a proper answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, well, its a copy paste of a comment, it isn't self contained, it isn't tuned to my satisfaction (perhaps one could avoid `FindShortestTour`, and its sandwiched between intimidating long and good looking answers

Answer (score 1):

Some really great answers.  Mine is not as flashy but it took me a few hours to get it so I'm throwing it up nevertheless.

I focused on making one month with the hope that I could make a month function and  find a way to merge months together for a longer calendar (haven't gotten that far, yet).

I've also gone the route of creating an item function for the days. this was first to make the code easier to read but then I realised that if I make the month a function that you could pass in your own item function.  That seems cool.  Although I don't know if it will work considering the item function references a few variables that would be in the function.

Some issues are that the shape is resizeable in the final grid.  I don't know how to turn that off.  Also, the frame disappears when the items are wrapped in a `Tooltip`; don't know it that is a bug. I also don't know how I'm going to get the month border sorted as yet. Is there such a thing as a frame function?  Maybe I'll try something with `MapIndexed`.

Well, enough chatter.  Here is what I have. Oh, I'm on version 10.0.1

**Update: Noticed and fixed a bug + , thanks to Pickett, fixed frame and resizing**

```
month = {2014, 10};
days = {Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, 
   Saturday};
lastDay = 
  QuantityMagnitude@
    DateDifference[month, DatePlus[month, {1, "Month"}], "Day"];
startWeekday = (Flatten@
     Position[True]@Map[DayMatchQ[month, #] &, days])[[1]];
weekCount = Quotient[(startWeekday - 9) + lastDay, 7] + 2;
dayPositions =(*day,weekday,week*)
  {#, Mod[# + startWeekday - 1 - Quotient[#, 7]*7  , 7] /. {0 -> 7},
     Quotient[(startWeekday - 9) + #, 7] + 2
     } & /@ Range[lastDay];
calendarTable = Table[Null, {weekdays, 7}, {weeks, weekCount}];

Clear[itemFunction];
itemFunction := (calendarTable[[#2, #3]] =
    Item[
     Tooltip[
      Graphics[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[#1, {1., lastDay}]], 
        Disk[]}],
      #1],
     Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Gray]
   ) &

Apply[itemFunction, dayPositions, {1}];

Deploy@Grid[calendarTable, Spacings -> 0, ItemSize -> 5]
```

That's all, folks.

Edmund

[image]

Comment: +1, regarding two of your question: You can make the graphics not resizable using `Deploy`. Add it in front of `Grid`, `Deploy@Grid[...`. `Item` is supposed to be the outermost head in the expression inside the grid, if it isn't things can break. If you put `Tooltip` around `Graphics` instead the frame is still visible.

Comment: @Pickett Thanks!  I noticed a bug in the above as well that I am trying to sort out.